# Why is the Innodb Memcached plugin being deprecated in MySQL 8.0.22?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, memcached, handler-socket

I originally used "the handlersocket" plugin for NoSQL access to InnoDB tables, then it eventually couldn't be built on newer versions so I migrated to the "Memcached" plugin which was being baked in by Oracle and seemed like a good long term replacement.

Now there is a notice on the [plugin documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-memcached.html) that "InnoDB memcached plugin is deprecated as of MySQL 8.0.22".

Does anyone know why, and second, does this just mean that it won't be baked in any more but can still be compiled when required, or that development of the plugin has ceased?  If it's the latter, are there newer/different options for socket access to tables that skip the overhead of the Query Optimizer?  I don't understand why something that adds so much efficiency and flexibility would be dropped so unceremoniously :(

Comment: I don't know why, but just wanted to point out there is still a [handlersocket plugin for MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/handlersocket/) ...

Comment: Thanks @dbdemon, I was aware they still built it in, but if I'm not mistaken, it was also removed from their releases after it stopped compiling against 5.7 I think.  Development stopped on handlersocket years and years ago now.... sadly, it was a great solution for a while!

Comment: "Deprecated" means "We're not removing it now, but we're warning you that it will be removed sometime in the future, so you should start migrating away from it."

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I understand what deprecated means. That doesn't mean it's not being dropped, just that it _will_ be dropped, so I'm not sure what you're getting at.

Comment: I was addressing your point "does this just mean that it won't be baked in any more"? But now I realize you didn't mean immediately, you meant "when it goes from deprecated to removed".

Comment: In the past MySQL has phased some features out by first making them non-default, and later removing them completely. I wouldn't be surprised if they do it with this, but don't know if you should depend on it.

Comment: @Barmar Ah, that makes more sense, thanks ;)  And yes, if CentOS and Redhat have been any indication, trust in the correct process is often misplaced, I wouldn't rely on anything like this when it comes to mission critical!

Comment: Right -- the best solution is to heed the warning and start phasing out your use of the deprecated feature soon.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The memcached plugin never did skip the overhead of InnoDB. It was an API, not a storage engine. Your data posted to the memcached plugin was still subject to transactions, still written to InnoDB's redo log, still cached in the buffer pool, etc. You could even access the same table via SQL. The only advantage to the memcached plugin was that it skipped SQL parsing, and because you couldn't do joins or searches except by primary key, that avoided a lot of complex choices for optimization.

I haven't seen a post that describes their reasons for deprecating this plugin. But any of the following reasons would be good ones:

- **It's insecure.** The memcached API has no authentication by default, and that's the way it was used in the memcached plugin. This is such a security gap that the [documentation discourages](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-memcached-security.html) users from storing "sensitive data" in the MySQL instance if the memcached plugin is enabled.

  That's a pretty strong statement for a database vendor to make! What would you think of an automobile whose maker said, "uh, you probably shouldn't let your family ride in this car."
- **It's confusing.** Is the memcached API providing access to a memcached instance? No. A memcached work-alike, that is an in-memory datastore? No. Is it as fast as memcached? No.
- **The XDevAPI provides NoSQL data access.** This is a more full-featured and secure API for MySQL, and it supports data like a document-oriented database. No doubt MySQL's product managers would rather developers use this, so they could have a better solution about non-SQL access to data in a MySQL Server.
- **It wasn't popular enough.** You used the memcached plugin, but not many other developers do. If they want to use memcached, it's not hard to actually use the real memcached service, which has the same advantages of a simple query interface, and also [is 2-3 times faster than the memcached plugin in MySQL](https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/03/29/mysql-5-6-innodb-memcached-plugin-as-a-caching-layer/).

Comment: Thanks Bill, I misspoke saying it skipped InnoDB, what I meant was the Query Optimization, so you're absolutely right there!  As for the insecurity, I understand what you mean, but it wasn't enabled by default, and securing access was done via firewalls and private cloud isolation, nothing insecure about it when done properly.  That said, I still see your point.  I'd forgotten about the XDevAPI so that's the answer I was looking for, it didn't come up in any searches I was doing looking for alternatives.  I remember looking at it and decided it was over complicated for our need, but now...